# How to write 'hello world' infotip shell extension?

Tags: .net, shell-extensions

I'd like to write a shell extension that adds a tooltip (infotip) for a particular file type. How can I do that?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144067(v=vs.85).aspx#_shell_reg_shell_ext_handlers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing shell extensions in .NET can be tricky. Luckily, there's a great library called [SharpShell](https://github.com/dwmkerr/sharpshell) which makes it easy to create and deploy shell extensions, including [info tips](https://github.com/dwmkerr/sharpshell#info-tip-handlers)!

Comment: Thanks this looks just what I want, let me try it out.

Answer (score 1):

This is documented here: [Infotip Customization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144067.aspx#infotips)

> Implement an object that supports IQueryInfo and then register that
>   object under the proper subkey in the registry (see Registering Shell
>   Extension Handlers below).

You must write a COM server that implements the [IQueryInfo interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761359.aspx). This server must be registered using standard COM ways, plus it must add some key to specify how it will affects tooltips.

Note you're not supposed to implement all this using .NET per Microsoft guidelines on this: [Guidance for Implementing In-Process Extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd758089.aspx)

Also, here is an old Delphi project that's interesting to consult on this: [Customizing Shell Infotips and implementing IQueryInfo](http://3http.com/book/delphi/%E6%95%B0%E6%8D%AE%E5%BA%93%E7%9B%B8%E5%85%B3/%E6%9F%A5%E8%AF%A2/SHELL%20EXTENSION%20INFOTIPS%20AND%20IQUERYINFO.HTM)